# work independently on two git branches

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-checkout

I had one git branche - BRANCH-1

Following are the steps I followed:

```
**STEP-1:** git checkout -b BRANCH-2 BRANCH-1 // creates BRANCH-2 from BRANCH-1 and switches to BRANCH-2
```

I make changes to some files in BRANCH-2
I do not commit

```
**STEP-2:** git checkout BRANCH-1 // switches to BRANCH-1
M       file.name
Switched to branch 'BRANCH-1'
```

After STEP-2, git moves to BRANCH-1 , but it also changes the file.name on BRANCH-1.

How do I checkout/switch between BRANCH-1 and BRANCH-2 with keeping their changes only to the respective branches

Comment: You should not be even attempting to switch branches if you have uncommitted/unstashed work.  I'm surprised you were able to switch from `BRANCH-2` to `BRANCH-1`.  Please review a Git tutorial.

Comment: commit or stash your changes

Comment: You shouldn't afraid to commit changes, even if they are temporary or can break things. You can always correct commits before pushing.